# how to get data from html with beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

the output of this code:

```
productNameText = down_page.find(id='productNameText')
print(productNameText)
```

gives:

```
[u'\n', <h1>

            Bold Print Short
        </h1>, u'\n']
```

How can I gently take only **Bold Print Short** text from here
Thanks

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'
after  AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Answer (score 1):

```
 productNameText = down_page.find(id='productNameText').get_text()
 print productNameText
```

[get_text() Beautiful Soup documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Comment: productNameText = down_page.find(id='productNameText').contents.get_text()